# How to populate an expandable listview in Android

Tags: java, android, adapter, expandablelistview, classnotfoundexception

I'm working with Expandable ListView for the first time and I found an example here:

http://android-adda.blogspot.ro/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html

I went through it, adapted it to my needs but the app would crash when applying the adapter. I copy-pasted the entire example, using even the given String arrays thinking I might be doing something wrong on that side.

Still, the error is the same.

Below you have the code for my activity + the custom adapter class included there. I've taken out non-related things like onClickListeners to other elements for obvious reasons.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
    public String[] parentArray = {
           "India",
           "Australia",
           "England",
           "South Africa"
         };
    public String[][] childArray = {
               {
                   "Sachin Tendulkar",
                   "Raina",
                   "Dhoni",
                   "Yuvi"
                    },
                    {
                   "Ponting",
                   "Adam Gilchrist",
                   "Michael Clarke"
                    },
                    {
                   "Andrew Strauss",
                   "kevin Peterson",
                   "Nasser Hussain"
                    },
                    {
                   "Graeme Smith",
                   "AB de villiers",
                   "Jacques Kallis"
                    }
                     };
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewschedule);

        getViews();
        setSpinnerAdapter();
        listview.setAdapter(new ExpAdapter(this));

    }

    public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

      private Context myContext;
      public ExpAdapter(Context context) {
       myContext = context;
      }
      public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return null;
      }

      public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return 0;
      }

      public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
       }

       TextView tvPlayerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);
       tvPlayerName.setText(childArray[groupPosition][childPosition]);

       return convertView;
      }

      public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       return childArray[groupPosition].length;
      }

      public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
       return null;
      }

      public int getGroupCount() {
       return parentArray.length;
      }

      public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
       return 0;
      }

      public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parentrow, null);
       }

       TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupName);
       tvGroupName.setText(parentArray[groupPosition]);

       return convertView;
      }

      public boolean hasStableIds() {
       return false;
      }

      public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return true;
      }
     }
}
```

Below this you have my log saying "class not found" mostly.

```
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1468)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.linearlayout
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
07-19 12:34:09.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
```

My getViews() method:

```
private void getViews(){
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arialnb.ttf");

        groupInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        groupInput.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightGrey));
        groupInput.setText("Grupa: (ex: 10201b)");

        titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        titleText.setTypeface(font);

        editDefault = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        homeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        daySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        listview = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        listview.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    }
```

The entire ViewSchedule.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/aceLightBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/aceDarkBlue" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/orarbuton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:text="@string/aceOrar"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/homebuton" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/editDefault" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
                android:ems="10" />

        </RelativeLayout>



        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2" >

        </ExpandableListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any sort of help with whatever I'm currently missing would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your viewschedule.xml layout file, and the contents of the `getViews()` method

Comment: does it force close as soon as you launch your app? Also it may help if you can post your import statements from the top of your Activity. And finally I'd say try to right click on your project in the Package Explorer and choose `Clean project` sometimes that will fix funky errors. Out of curiosity why do you have a 0 height/width LinearLayout inside the relativeLayout2?

Comment: The app force-closes at whatever stage I set the listview adapter. I'll edit and add the rest of the code and also include the childrow.xml and parentrow.xml, maybe I'm missing something there. It's all becoming a bit of a blur to me after working on it all this time

Comment: And that layout is there so it distracts focus from the EditText. It's a bit of a hacky method, but it works. In short it keeps the keyboard from popping up when entering the Activity or when changing screen orientation

Comment: I just got it... the build path, for whatever reason to the TextView in childrow.xml, portrait folder was broken and that caused it to crash... Thanks a lot for your input. It was really helpful to have someone look at it from the outside

Comment: No problem, glad you got it fixed. Can you post an answer that tells what was wrong and how you fixed it so this will be easier to find and solve for people in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, thanks to [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507810/tim) who had the right idea that I clean up the project.

I have 2 separate layout folders for this app, a landscape and a portrait folder. For whatever reason, the TextView path in the portrait folder, in the parentrow.xml was broken.

All I had to do was click on "Change to TextView" in the GUI editor and it worked fine.

Worth mentioning that this error was not signaled by Eclipse and I was only aware of it once I started going through the xml files by hand.